# How to use twitter-bootstrap spans from right to left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If I want to place an element on the right of the screen for example the final 3 spans and want white space to the left of them (not use the spans) is this possible to achieve on twitter-bootstrap and if so how?  Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span9"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

And you can also do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3 offset9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks I'd completely forgotten about offset

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pull-right` and `pull-left`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3 pull-right"></div>
  <div class="span6 pull-left"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well the spans work in 12 sections, so if you wanted 3 spans to the left, you would just want to have a span that consumes the rest of the space

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6"></div>
  <div class="span2"></div>
  <div class="span2"></div>
  <div class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

alternatively you can use the offset

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span2 offset6"></div>
  <div class="span2"></div>
  <div class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: or, just use `<div class="row"><div class="span6"></div></div>` if you want the final 3 span spaces to be blank..in the next `row` it will not interfere with the previous `row`